# News Web Part: Site Links do not render correctly when using multi site news

Tags: modern-experience, sharepoint-news

When using the News web part in multi site mode (Select sites), the site link does not render a link to the news item's parent site. The link title is correct, but the link url always points to the home of the site that the news part is being hosted on.

I have tested this against 4-5 tenants and the behavior is the same.

It looks like the api endpoint for multi site news (/_api/v2.1/getMultiSiteNews) doesn't return the link in the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few weeks later, this gradually started working across all the affected tenants. Seems like a fix was rolled out.